# На сайте есть n-блоков, у всех уникальный id. Необходимо отправлять get-запрос при отображении каждого из этих блоков

Tags: javascript, php, html

Данный скрипт срабатывает на каждом блоке раз по 20 за 1 прокрутку, как сделать так, чтобы срабатывало 1 раз?

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.block {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="1">Блок 1</div>
<script>function scrollTracking1(){
    var tsr_id = '1';
    var stri = 'tsr_id='+tsr_id;
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $('#1').offset().top;
    var eh = $('#1').outerHeight();
    
    if (et >= wt && et + eh <= wh + wt){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            $.get('/postback/views.php', (stri), function(data) { 
            console.log(data); // ответ от сервера
        });
        }
        block_show = true;
    } else {
        block_show = false;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTracking1();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scrollTracking1();
});</script>
<div class="block" id="2">Блок 2</div>
<script>function scrollTracking2(){
    var tsr_id = '2';
    var stri = 'tsr_id='+tsr_id;
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $('#2').offset().top;
    var eh = $('#2').outerHeight();
    
    if (et >= wt && et + eh <= wh + wt){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            $.get('/postback/views.php', (stri), function(data) { 
            console.log(data); // ответ от сервера
        });
        }
        block_show = true;
    } else {
        block_show = false;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTracking2();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scrollTracking2();
});</script>
<div class="block" id="3">Блок 3</div>
<script>function scrollTracking3(){
    var tsr_id = '3';
    var stri = 'tsr_id='+tsr_id;
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $('#3').offset().top;
    var eh = $('#3').outerHeight();
    
    if (et >= wt && et + eh <= wh + wt){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            $.get('/postback/views.php', (stri), function(data) { 
            console.log(data); // ответ от сервера
        });
        }
        block_show = true;
    } else {
        block_show = false;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTracking3();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scrollTracking3();
});</script>
<div class="block" id="4">Блок 4</div>
<script>function scrollTracking4(){
    var tsr_id = '4';
    var stri = 'tsr_id='+tsr_id;
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $('#4').offset().top;
    var eh = $('#4').outerHeight();
    
    if (et >= wt && et + eh <= wh + wt){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            $.get('/postback/views.php', (stri), function(data) { 
            console.log(data); // ответ от сервера
        });
        }
        block_show = true;
    } else {
        block_show = false;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTracking4();
});
    
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scrollTracking4();
});</script>
```

Comment: Данный скрипт срабатывает на каждом блоке раз по 20 за 1 прокрутку, как сделать так, чтобы срабатывало 1 раз?

Comment: Вешать "флаг" на уже отправленный элемент, чтобы скрипт встречая этот "флаг" не отправлял запрос **снова**. Например.